# When triggered, run script at top of the hour

Tags: centos, bash, scripting, cron, system-monitoring

I have a service that must be started at the top of the hour, any hour. Whenever that service goes down (during a reboot, etc) PRTG Network Monitor will know. PRTG has the ability to run a script when a specified service goes down. I want PRTG to run a script to start the service at the next available top of the hour. So if it goes down at 6:42pm, I want it to start at 7pm. If it goes down at 2:01am, I want it to start again at 3am, etc. This command would only need to happen once, every time that PRTG triggers it and notices that the service is down.

Google says cron would be best for this, but I don't want it to be recurring.

at command sounds nice, but how do I make it work for top of the hour only, without listing a specific hour?

Any help is appreciated.

CentOS 6.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Google says cron would be best for this, but I don't want it to be
>   recurring.

Forget about PRTG for anything but monitoring and notifications. It's true - cron jobs *are* recurring. However, all you need to do is write a simple wrapper script that gets run by cron at the top of each hour - this script would:

1. Check if your program is running. If it is, then exit.
2. If the process is not running, start it.

Comment: Ok, so would this wrapper script run every minute or something to do the check to see if the program is running? Also, the process cannot just start when the script finds it is stopped. It must be started at the top of the hour. Would this method allow for that?

Comment: Why would it need to run every minute? All you care about is that, if it's not running, that it gets started at the top of every hour. So, as I said above, the cron would run hourly.

Comment: OH! So Cron would run at the top of every hour, and if the program isn't running it starts it. Right?

Comment: Right, as I said in my answer. :)

Comment: Yeah I guess I read it wrong the first time :P Thanks for your patience and your help! :)

Comment: No problem. Good luck and have a good weekend.